# Mysql table crash, what do I need to do to fix this

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, myisam

Table '.\mysql\proc' is marked as crashed and should be repaired.

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MyISAM table. It is easy to fix. Login to mysql and run this

```
mysql> REPAIR TABLE mysql.proc;
```

and you should be good to go.

BTW this is where stored procedure are stored.